# Sub filters in LDAP query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

how will be the query if I want only users from OU's having name started with "sales".

for example:

```
(&(objectCategory=person))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking there are no ways to query users by their OU name, because a) users do not usually contain any knowledge about OU they belong to (unlike groups membership for example) and therefore nothing can be added to filter b) LDAP filters are quite limited and there are no such thing as sub-filter or sub-query.

Partial solution of the problem could be setting ldap_search's BaseDN parameter to OU path.

More complex queries are usually handled with help of some kind of client side code.

Comment: Thanx, if it will be a group not ou than how can i do this?

Comment: for example: (&(objectCategory=person)(memberof=cn=FooUsers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))

Answer (score 0):

Objects in the directory database have associated with them an attribute `objectClass` which values determine which attributes must or may be included in the object. The `organizationalPerson` and its descendant `inetOrgPerson` allow the inclusion of the `ou` attribute in the object. If your application requires locating objects that have an `ou` attribute with a particular value, include the `ou` in an *equality filter*:

```
(ou=organization name)
```

or to limit the objects returned from the search request to those with an `ou` attribute of the exact case, use an [*extensible match filter*](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/#extensible-match-filter) (professional quality servers that are LDAP compliant support the extensible match filter):

```
(ou:caseExactMatch:=Organization Name)
```

or to make a similar determination if the object is subordinate to an `ou`, that is, the entry's DN is something like `uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` use an extensible match filter that includes the DN:

```
(ou:dn:caseExactMatch:=people)
```

or to determine which objects have the attribute `ou` use a "presence filter":

```
(ou=*)
```

All of the above techniques most likely require that the `ou` attribute be indexed.  See *["Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)* for more general information about search requests and responses.